# call footer.php from child-theme

Tags: function, footer, require-once

I'm quite struggling how to implement the footer.php into the child-them and call it correctly.
In the parent theme it is saved here: theme/header-footer-grid/Core/Builder/Footer.php
I saved the footer into the child location: child_theme/header-footer-grid/Core/Builder/Footer.php

Content footer.php:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Footer class for Header Footer Grid.
 *
 * Name:    Header Footer Grid
 * Author:  Bogdan Preda <bogdan.preda@themeisle.com>
 *
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @package HFG
 */

namespace HFG\Core\Builder;

use HFG\Main;
use Neve\Core\Theme_Info;

/**
 * Class Footer
 *
 * @package HFG\Core\Builder
 */
class Footer extends Abstract_Builder {
    use Theme_Info;

    /**
     * Builder name.
     */
    const BUILDER_NAME = 'footer';

    /**
     * Footer constructor.
     *
     * @since   1.0.0
     * @access  public
     */
    public function init() {
        $this->set_property( 'title', __( 'Footer', 'neve' ) );
        $this->set_property( 'columns_layout', true );
        $this->set_property(
            'description',
            apply_filters(
                'hfg_footer_panel_description',
                sprintf(
                /* translators: %s link to documentation */
                    esc_html__( 'Design your %1$s by dragging, dropping and resizing all the elements in real-time. %2$s.', 'neve' ),
                    /* translators: %s builder type */
                    $this->get_property( 'title' ),
                    /* translators: %s link text */
                    sprintf(
                        '<br/><a target="_blank" rel="external noopener noreferrer" href="https://docs.themeisle.com/article/946-neve-doc#footer-builder"><span class="screen-reader-text">%s</span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" focusable="false" role="img" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="12" height="12" style="margin-right: 5px;"><path fill="currentColor" d="M432 320H400a16 16 0 0 0-16 16V448H64V128H208a16 16 0 0 0 16-16V80a16 16 0 0 0-16-16H48A48 48 0 0 0 0 112V464a48 48 0 0 0 48 48H400a48 48 0 0 0 48-48V336A16 16 0 0 0 432 320ZM488 0h-128c-21.4 0-32 25.9-17 41l35.7 35.7L135 320.4a24 24 0 0 0 0 34L157.7 377a24 24 0 0 0 34 0L435.3 133.3 471 169c15 15 41 4.5 41-17V24A24 24 0 0 0 488 0Z"/></svg>%s</a>',
                        esc_html__( '(opens in a new tab)', 'neve' ),
                        esc_html__( 'Read full documentation', 'neve' )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        $this->set_property(
            'instructions_array',
            array(
                'description' => sprintf(
                /* translators: 1: builder, 2: builder symbol */
                    esc_attr__( 'Welcome to the %1$s builder! Click the %2$s button to add a new component or follow the Quick Links.', 'neve' ),
                    $this->get_property( 'title' ),
                    '+'
                ),
                'quickLinks'  => array(
                    'footer_copyright_content'            => array(
                        'label' => esc_html__( 'Change Copyright', 'neve' ),
                        'icon'  => 'dashicons-nametag',
                        'url'   => $this->has_valid_addons() ? null : tsdk_utmify( 'https://themeisle.com/themes/neve/upgrade/', 'copyright' ),
                    ),
                    'hfg_footer_layout_bottom_background' => array(
                        'label' => esc_html__( 'Change Footer Color', 'neve' ),
                        'icon'  => 'dashicons-admin-appearance',
                    ),
                ),
            )
        );
        $this->devices = [
            'desktop' => __( 'Footer', 'neve' ),
        ];

        /**
         * Fix legacy search widget display in footer
         * Only applies for versions < 5.8
         */
        add_filter(
            'dynamic_sidebar_params',
            function ( $params ) {
                $processed_params        = [];
                $has_legacy_search_style = apply_filters( 'neve_has_legacy_search_style_filter', false );
                foreach ( $params as $param ) {
                    if ( isset( $param['before_widget'] ) && strpos( $param['before_widget'], 'widget_search' ) !== false && $has_legacy_search_style === false ) {
                        $param['before_widget'] = '<style type="text/css">.widget_search .search-form .search-submit, .widget_search .search-form .search-field { height: auto; }</style>' . $param['before_widget'];
                        add_filter( 'neve_has_legacy_search_style_filter', '__return_true' );
                    }
                    array_push( $processed_params, $param );
                }

                return $processed_params;
            }
        );

        add_action( 'neve_after_slot_component', [ $this, 'add_footer_component' ], 10, 3 );
    }

    /**
     * Add footer component.
     *
     * @param string $builder Builder slug.
     * @param string $row Row slug.
     * @param string $slot Slot name.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function add_footer_component( $builder, $row, $slot ) {
        if ( $this->has_valid_addons() ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( $builder !== self::BUILDER_NAME ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( $row !== 'bottom' ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( $slot !== 'left' ) {
            return;
        }

        $output  = '<div class="builder-item"><div class="item--inner"><div class="component-wrap"><div>';
        $output .= sprintf(
        /* translators: %1$s is Theme Name ( Neve ), %2$s is WordPress */
            esc_html__( '%1$s | Powered by %2$s', 'neve' ),
            wp_kses_post( '<p><a href="https://themeisle.com/themes/neve/" rel="nofollow">Neve</a>' ),
            wp_kses_post( '<a href="http://wordpress.org" rel="nofollow">WordPress</a></p>' )
        );
        $output .= '</div></div></div></div>';


        echo wp_kses_post( $output );
    }

    /**
     * Method called via hook.
     *
     * @since   1.0.0
     * @access  public
     */
    public function load_template() {

        Main::get_instance()->load( 'footer-wrapper' );
    }

    /**
     * Render builder row.
     *
     * @param string $device_id The device id.
     * @param string $row_id The row id.
     * @param array  $row_details Row data.
     */
    public function render_row( $device_id, $row_id, $row_details ) {
        Main::get_instance()->load( 'footer-row-wrapper' );
    }

    /**
     * Get builder id.
     *
     * @return string Builder id.
     */
    public function get_id() {
        return self::BUILDER_NAME;
    }

    /**
     * Overrides parent method to limit rows.
     *
     * @return array
     * @since   1.0.0
     * @access  protected
     */
    protected function get_rows() {
        if ( neve_is_new_builder() ) {
            return [
                'top'    => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Footer Top', 'neve' ),
                    'description' => $this->get_property( 'description' ),
                ),
                'main'   => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Footer Main', 'neve' ),
                    'description' => $this->get_property( 'description' ),
                ),
                'bottom' => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Footer Bottom', 'neve' ),
                    'description' => $this->get_property( 'description' ),
                ),
            ];
        }

        return [
            'top'    => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Footer Top', 'neve' ),
                'description' => $this->get_property( 'description' ),
            ),
            'bottom' => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Footer Bottom', 'neve' ),
                'description' => $this->get_property( 'description' ),
            ),
        ];
    }
}
```

Content function.php:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'neve_child_load_css' ) ):
    /**
     * Load CSS file.
     */
    function neve_child_load_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'neve-child-style', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'neve-style' ), NEVE_VERSION );
    }

require_once( get_stylesheet_directory(). '/header-footer-grid/Core/Builder/Footer.php' ); 

endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'neve_child_load_css', 20 );
```

Failure Message when saving the function.php:
abstract_builder missing

If I copy the abstract_builder.php from the parent into the child location, saving the function.php works, but the site crashes.

Does anyone has some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

use css to hide it

```
.nv-footer-content > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(2) {    display: none; }
```